# Slick - inserting row using an object instead of tuple

Tags: scala, orm, slick

I'm an experienced Java developer who's trying to learn Scala and Slick at the same time.  All the examples I found for inserting rows into a table with Slick seem to construct a tuple using **positional** arguments.  For example, I'll take from the [official lightbend documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting):

```
val insertActions = DBIO.seq(
  coffees += ("Colombian", 101, 7.99, 0, 0),

  coffees ++= Seq(
    ("French_Roast", 49, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("Espresso",    150, 9.99, 0, 0)
  ),

  // "sales" and "total" will use the default value 0:
  coffees.map(c => (c.name, c.supID, c.price)) += ("Colombian_Decaf", 101, 8.99)
)
```

But relying on positional arguments is a bug waiting to happen, and it's also difficult to read.  Is there a more reader-friendly and less bug prone way of doing this?  Like with the coffee object?

I'm picturing something like this:

```
val insertActions = DBIO.seq(
    coffees += new Coffee(name="Colombian", id=101, price=7.99, foo=0, bar=0)

    coffees ++= Seq(
        new Coffee (name= "French_Roast", id=49, price=8.99, foo=0, bar=0),
        new Coffee (name = "Espresso",    id = 150, price=9.99, foo=0, bar=0)
    )
)
```

Apologies if my code looks like Java, that's where I'm coming from.  But you get the idea of what I want.  Any ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to define a case class, say `Coffee` with the same fields as the table row class `Coffees`'s.  The catch is that you would need to modify class `Coffees` to extend `Table[Coffee]` and provide the bidirectional mapping using `<>` for the `*` projection:

```
case class Coffee(name, supID, price)

class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[Coffee](tag, "USERS") {
  // ...
  def * = (name, supID, price) <> (Coffee.tupled, Coffee.unapply)
}
```

You should then be able to perform `insert` like:

```
val insertActions = DBIO.seq(
  coffees += Coffee(name = "Colombian", supID = 101, price = 7.99),
  // ...
)
```

More details can be found in this [Slick doc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables).